# How to match signs in Bash?

Tags: regex, bash

How to match below signs in Bash?

+

-

/

*

This my code which I try to use but it did not work.

```
is_sign(){
yoursign=$1
re="^[+,-,\/,\*]$"
if ! [[ $yoursign =~ $re ]] ; then
   echo "Not a sign"
  return 2
else
  return 0
fi
}

is_sign $1
```

Comment: Use `re='^[+/*-]$'` if you need a regex

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew please post that as an answer

Comment: `/` is not a special character in `regex`. It does not need escaping in any context. `*` does not need escaping in character classes (`[...]`). Depending on the tool or language, the unneeded escape characters (``\``) are ignored or they represent themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern you used contains the following issues:

- You escape special characters thinking it will make them literal chars, but in fact, in POSIX bracket expressions, backslashes are treated as regular literal backslashes, and all you did is you also allow a literal `\` to be matched with the regex
- `-` must be either at the start or end of a POSIX bracket expression if you want to match a literal hyphen
- By adding commas to the regex, it can now also match a comma.

Use

```
re='^[+/*-]$'
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/aPY8FG):

```
is_sign() {
yoursign=$1
re='^[+/*-]$'
if ! [[ $yoursign =~ $re ]] ; then
  echo "Not a sign"
  #return 2
else
  echo "Yeah, is a sign"
  #return 0
fi
}

echo "$(is_sign "+")" # => Yeah, is a sign
echo "$(is_sign "m")" # => Not a sign
```

Comment: @dabal_69 It depends on what you mean by "does not work". It works very well in Linux. See my demo.

Comment: if you quote your command substitutions `"$(...)"` I'll upvote your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You have two solutions:

Regular expression:

```
re='^[+/*-]$'
if ! [[ $yoursign =~ $re ]] ; then
```

Glob:

```
glob='[+/*-]'
if ! [[ $yoursign == $glob ]] ; then
```

Please note that the minus sign `-` is special in a character class (both in a glob and in a regular expression), so you need to either put it in the beginning or at the end